# Android updating tree of views

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

The problem:

I have a class, inherited from `LinearLayout`.
This class creates some buttons in the constructor and puts them into itself using `addChild()`.
I've overloaded method `onSizeCHanged` and I want to add some childs in this method.
But changes have no effect until one of the other buttons clicked.

So, I need to press some of existing buttons and after that views which I've added appear.
(by the way, only buttons with ontouchlistener do it. buttons without listener cannot make new views appeared).

How to add views in `onSizeChange` method to do them appeared immediately?

ADDITION:
Methods `forceLayout()` and `requestLayout()` cannot work.

Comment: are you overriding onLayout()?

Comment: no, i'm not overriding onLayout

Answer (score 0):

I have not extended LinearLayout myself but I read up on the class a bit and I think you need to override onLayout() and add your child views in it. Check the docs and see if it helps

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#onLayout(boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was: making a simple boolean flag, setting it "true" im onSizeChanged and calling "invalidate".

In method "onDraw" checking if flag is true and if it is so, calling requestLayout. Then setting flag to false.